# Fast performance when searching for strings in a 100 million record database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, full-text-search, freetext

Is it possible to get a result within a few seconds? I am using SQL server and have a large table contains millions of records. I wish to search on field called keyword, but performing a FREETEXT or even CONTAINS search when using full text is very slow (10s of seconds). Is there any fast approach to being able to rapidly find words using substrings (i.e. type 'bolt' and 'thunderbolt' be returned) in a quick and efficient manner on this scale?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Create a `non-clustered index` for the column `keyword` on which you perform like search.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_keyword
    ON table (keyword); 
GO
```

[More](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173275/Clustered-and-Non-Clustered-Index-in-SQL-2005)

Comment: i've already done this, it's OK for a few hundred thousand customers, but after that it's just too slow

Comment: SQL Server is not designed for providing such high full-text search performance. To achieve your goal, you may need to consider open source solutions such as Lucene or other proprietary solutions.